# Use SVG version of SE logo

Tags: feature-request, bug, design, logo, retina

This is the view of the [login screen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/login) (when not logged in):

[image]

The Stack Exchange logo is a blurry [PNG version](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackexchange/img/logo.png?v=ca40535fea2d) at that scale. The font *size* is also different to the surrounding text. Why is this version used when there is a perfectly reasonable SVG version in the top bar/footer of the [Stack Exchange website](https://stackexchange.com/)?

[image]

```
<a href="https://stackexchange.com">
  <svg aria-hidden="true" class="svg-icon native iconLogoSE" width="150" height="35" viewBox="0 0 150 35">
    <g>
      <path d="M43.46 30.88l-2.86-4.85-1.5 1.76v3.09h-2.05V16.12h2.05v9.1l3.96-4.85h2.49L42 24.5l4 6.38h-2.53zM32.39 31c-2.3 0-4.54-1.45-4.54-5.39 0-3.93 2.25-5.36 4.54-5.36 1.4 0 2.39.41 3.35 1.47l-1.4 1.4c-.65-.72-1.15-.99-1.95-.99a2.3 2.3 0 0 0-1.9.93c-.43.58-.6 1.33-.6 2.55 0 1.23.17 2 .6 2.57.45.6 1.11.93 1.9.93.8 0 1.3-.26 1.95-.99l1.4 1.39A4.14 4.14 0 0 1 32.4 31zm-8.2-4.77H21.8c-1.2 0-1.83.56-1.83 1.52 0 .95.59 1.49 1.87 1.49.79 0 1.37-.06 1.91-.6.3-.31.44-.81.44-1.56v-.85zm.04 4.65v-.96c-.74.77-1.44 1.08-2.7 1.08-1.27 0-2.12-.31-2.74-.95a3.28 3.28 0 0 1-.8-2.26c0-1.76 1.18-3.03 3.51-3.03h2.7v-.74c0-1.33-.65-1.97-2.24-1.97-1.12 0-1.66.27-2.23 1.01l-1.34-1.3c.96-1.16 1.97-1.51 3.65-1.51 2.8 0 4.2 1.22 4.2 3.6v7.03h-2zm-9.26 0c-1.9 0-2.8-1.41-2.8-2.93v-5.78h-1.16v-1.61h1.17v-3.2h2.05v3.2h1.97v1.61h-1.97v5.68c0 .77.36 1.22 1.12 1.22h.85v1.8h-1.23zm-9.9.12c-2.16 0-3.7-.52-5.07-1.95l1.45-1.47A4.64 4.64 0 0 0 5.1 29c1.87 0 2.96-.83 2.96-2.26 0-.64-.18-1.18-.56-1.53-.37-.35-.73-.5-1.57-.62l-1.69-.25a4.83 4.83 0 0 1-2.71-1.18 3.73 3.73 0 0 1-1.05-2.82C.48 17.76 2.3 16 5.27 16c1.88 0 3.21.5 4.44 1.68l-1.4 1.4a4.12 4.12 0 0 0-3.1-1.13c-1.7 0-2.62 1-2.62 2.3 0 .54.16 1.01.54 1.36.37.34.95.58 1.61.69l1.63.25c1.33.2 2.07.54 2.67 1.1.79.7 1.17 1.76 1.17 3.02 0 2.71-2.15 4.33-5.15 4.33z"
      fill="#020303" />
      <path d="M133.14 23.38a1.88 1.88 0 0 0-1.8-1.12 1.9 1.9 0 0 0-1.82 1.12c-.16.39-.22.68-.24 1.15h4.1a2.94 2.94 0 0 0-.24-1.15zm-3.86 3c0 1.37.85 2.39 2.36 2.39a3 3 0 0 0 2.45-1.02l1.64 1.6a5.16 5.16 0 0 1-4.1 1.69c-2.56 0-5.01-1.16-5.01-5.52 0-3.5 1.9-5.49 4.71-5.49 3.01 0 4.71 2.2 4.71 5.14v1.2h-6.76zm-9.64-3.93c-1.6 0-1.76 1.36-1.76 2.79 0 1.42.16 2.8 1.76 2.8s1.79-1.38 1.79-2.8c0-1.43-.19-2.8-1.79-2.8zm-.27 12.53c-1.66 0-2.8-.33-3.92-1.4l1.68-1.7c.6.58 1.2.83 2.12.83 1.62 0 2.18-1.14 2.18-2.23v-1.1a3.18 3.18 0 0 1-2.58 1.08 3.61 3.61 0 0 1-2.57-.95c-1.02-1.01-1.1-2.4-1.1-4.27 0-1.88.08-3.25 1.1-4.26.6-.6 1.54-.95 2.6-.95 1.14 0 1.88.31 2.63 1.14v-1.01h2.62v10.36c0 2.58-1.85 4.46-4.76 4.46zm-9.34-4.07v-6.5c0-1.47-.93-1.96-1.78-1.96s-1.81.5-1.81 1.96v6.5h-2.7V20.16h2.64v.99a3.7 3.7 0 0 1 2.7-1.12 3.5 3.5 0 0 1 2.55.95c.87.87 1.1 1.88 1.1 3.06v6.87h-2.7zm-11.9-4.54H96c-.98 0-1.52.45-1.52 1.22 0 .74.5 1.24 1.56 1.24.75 0 1.22-.06 1.7-.52.3-.27.4-.7.4-1.36v-.58zm.07 4.54v-.93c-.73.73-1.41 1.04-2.66 1.04-1.22 0-2.12-.31-2.76-.95-.58-.6-.9-1.47-.9-2.42 0-1.71 1.2-3.12 3.7-3.12h2.56V24c0-1.18-.58-1.7-2.02-1.7-1.04 0-1.51.25-2.07.9l-1.73-1.68c1.06-1.16 2.1-1.49 3.9-1.49 3.04 0 4.62 1.28 4.62 3.8v7.08H98.2zm-11.15 0v-6.56c0-1.43-.91-1.9-1.76-1.9s-1.75.5-1.75 1.9v6.56h-2.7v-14.7h2.7v4.94a3.58 3.58 0 0 1 2.6-1.12c2.36 0 3.61 1.65 3.61 3.93v6.95h-2.7zm-11.87.13c-2.16 0-4.84-1.16-4.84-5.52 0-4.35 2.68-5.49 4.84-5.49 1.5 0 2.61.46 3.57 1.45l-1.83 1.81c-.56-.6-1.04-.84-1.74-.84-.65 0-1.15.23-1.54.7-.41.52-.6 1.24-.6 2.37 0 1.14.19 1.88.6 2.4.4.47.9.7 1.54.7.7 0 1.18-.25 1.74-.85l1.83 1.8a4.64 4.64 0 0 1-3.57 1.47zm-8.89-.13l-2-3.22-1.96 3.22h-3.24l3.73-5.49-3.59-5.26h3.24l1.83 3.07 1.85-3.07h3.23l-3.59 5.26 3.74 5.5h-3.24zm-18.29 0v-14.7h9.74v2.56h-6.85v3.45h5.83v2.56H50.9v3.57h6.85v2.56H48z"
      fill="#205196" />
      <path d="M150 3h-15v-.5c0-1.3 1.21-2.5 2.5-2.5h10c1.3 0 2.5 1.2 2.5 2.5V3z" fill="#8FD8F7"
      />
      <path d="M135 12v.5c0 1.3 1.21 2.5 2.5 2.5h6.5v3l3-3h.5c1.3 0 2.5-1.2 2.5-2.5V12h-15z"
      fill="#155397" />
      <path fill="#2D6DB5" d="M135 8v3h15V8z" />
      <path fill="#46A2D9" d="M135 4v3h15V4z" />
    </g>
  </svg>
</a>
```

Can this be updated?

Technically, the same goes for the main SE logo on the main [SE page](//stackexchange.com):

[image]

Comment: Probably overlook, adding bug tag.